# How to find libicucore.dylib in xcode7?

Tags: ios, google-maps

In order to implement google map into my project i need to add the libicucore.dylib framework. But,I can't find that. So, what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for Xcode 7 follow the following steps:

**Go to Build Phases** > **Link Binary with Libraries** > + > **Add other**

While in the file selection window press: "CMD"+Shift+G (i.e. Go to folder) and type `/usr/lib/`
From `/usr/lib` find and add : `libicucore.dylib`

Comment: that is wrong im afraid. oh it may work ok but thats not how it should be done AND may break easily in the future

Comment: and? sorry but the public forums are not really relevant. I use tbds all the time and they work fine and are the way to go -- if it doesn't work in some cases, ok.. apply your workaround THEN :) but try to do it right at first

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 7 follow the following steps:

1. Go to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries > +
2. search for 'ice'
3. select libicucore.tbd
4. press  done

[image]